# Data Feed Manager & Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to have information about Data Feed Manager. Is it possible to send it is produced on ebay or google shopping ?
How this this past? ebay should create an account to import the products ?
I have configurable product how will it be showing on google shopping?

Comment: check m2epro.com , its your best option to work with multichannel from magento and its free (for the moment)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have another question if I use the feed to import my products on ebay. If I install m2e are what I would need to return products with m2e?

Comment: Why M2E Pro is different from other Multi Channel providers? M2E Pro uses only native capabilities of Magento without creating any additional layers (i.e. middleware) or utilisation of a cloud (i.e. saving merchant’s data off site). It just fully integrates Magento backend with eBay, Amazon & Rakuten marketplaces around the globe. Think of eBay, Amazon & Rakuten becoming a integral part of your Magento system.

Comment: http://m2epro.com/features/

Answer (score 0):

By default, magento does not contain the ability to generate the data feeds for Google Shopping or eBay.

To generate magento google shopping data feed, you can use ready-made extension that already contains data feed templates and you only need configure filtering of products for uploading.

https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-product-feeds-generator.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have another question I only want to send products on google shopping. On ebay I would send products via a stream its will run faster. But if I install m2e are what it will synchronize what I already send streaming?